# Office Web App 2013 doesn't work : Error 1000, 1026 in events viewers

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

I have problems in my developpement environment for Sharepoint Foundation Server 2013. My topology : 
1 server with AD, SP, SQL and dev tools (windows server 2012 R2);
1 server with OfficeWebApps 2013 (windows server 2012 R2)

It's impossible to open/edit documents in sharepoint with Office web apps (with classic user). But, of course, i can download the file.
When i load a file, i can see message : *Server Error. We're sorry. An error has occurred. We've logged the error for the server administrator.*

It's the same error message with Word, Excel, powerpoint or Onenote file.
In addition, the use of CPU is 100% ! Used by System processus and Windows Problem Reporting.

In events viewer (of OWA server), there are two errors which apppear each minutes :

```
**[ .NET runtime error 1026 ]**
Application: Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.EcsWatchdog.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_Item(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.WSServiceInstanceFinderAdapter..ctor()
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.HostEnvironment.LoadAdapterInstance(AdapterLoadInformation, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.HostEnvironment+AdapterLoadInformation1+<>c__DisplayClass17[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<BuildInstance>b__16()
   at System.Lazy1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].LazyInitValue()
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.ServiceInstanceFinder.RefreshList(System.Object)
Exception Info: Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.OfficeServiceException
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.ServiceInstanceFinder.RefreshList(System.Object)
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.ServiceInstanceFinder..cctor()
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.ServiceInstanceFinder.GetLocalAgentInstance(Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.OfficeServiceType)
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.WatchdogHelper.PrepareRegistrations(Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.OfficeServiceType)
   at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.WatchdogHelper.WatchMachines(Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.OfficeServiceType, CheckServiceInstance, Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.OfficeServiceType, System.String)
   at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.EcsWatchdog.Program.Main()
```

And:

```
**[ Application Error error 1000 ]**
Faulting application name: pptviewerbackendwatchdog.exe, version: 15.0.4502.1000, time stamp: 0x512d2645
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18666, time stamp: 0x58f33794
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00000000000095fc
Faulting process id: 0x153c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3216a56b1c1bb
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web Apps\PowerPointViewingServicesWatchdog_App\pptviewerbackendwatchdog.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 949eafc7-8d5d-11e7-80cd-000d3a27a53b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I tried a lot of things like remove (with `Remove-OfficeWebAppsMachine`) and recreate OWA, install KB, update .NET, ...

I specify, the xml data in http://machine-owa/hosting/discovery is accessible from 2 servers.

Anyone knows about this problem?

Comment: Is there anything else installed on the OWA-Machine (like Office, SharePoint Designer, ...)?

Comment: Nothing else installed. Only Office Web Apps 2013, Chrome and Notepad++ ...